# How to set JSON array to state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this bellow App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'


class Axios extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            item : '',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/capital/lima')
        .then( response => {
            const data = response.data.map(( data )=>{
                this.setState({
                    item : data
                });
            });
        })
        .catch( error => {
            alert( error );
        });
    }

    prepare() {
        console.log( this.state.item );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.prepare()}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Axios;
```

My goal is to get the **common** name from this API: `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/capital/lima`

Now on `componentDidMount()` method, I need to set the API return data to the `item` state so that I can loop through using the `prepare` method.

But I don't have any idea how to set the API return **array JSON data** to the `item` state?

Comment: `response.json()` do first then assign it

Comment: @AshishKamble what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `state.item` to a blank array.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        item : [],
    }
}
```

In `componentDidMount()`, update the code to accept `response` :

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/capital/lima')
    .then( response => {
        this.setState({
                item : response.data
            });
    })
    .catch( error => {
        alert( error );
    });
}
```

In `render()`, you can use map on `state.item` and can loop on it.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.state.item.map(data,index)=>(
              //some UI mapping to each `data` in `item` array
        )}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: yeah, this will work

Comment: Thanks Pranay BInju, I am checking it.

Comment: `prepare() {
    return(
        this.state.item.map( ( data ) => {
            <li>{ data.name.common }</li>
            // console.log( data.name.common )
        })
        
    )
}` could you tell me why this is not working?

Comment: Basically, I want to list all the countries. `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all`

Comment: Anyways, I solved it.

Comment: you need to return ` <li>` from `map` function. Hope you have done that.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do assing `response.data` to `item` as:

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/capital/lima")
    .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          item: response.data
        })
      })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check this out.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Axios extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      item: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/capital/lima")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          item: response && response.data
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
  
  prepare() {
    return <div>{console.log("Item", this.state.item)}</div>;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.prepare()}</div>;
  }
}

export default Axios;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).